# Constructer in Javascript does not return correct value that is passed by prototype function

Tags: javascript

I have written a code with constructer Vector(it has two parameters) and I wish to pass different set of parameters through a prototype function and want to sum up the values for both set of parameters.

But I am facing a issue with printing final Vector.

```
function Vector(x, y) {

    this.x = x;

    this.y = y;

    console.log(x, y);//initially this prints (3,3)

    return (x, y);
}



Vector.prototype.plus = function (a, b) {

    this.x = this.x + a;
    this.y = this.y + b;
    console.log(this.x, this.y);// After passing (1,9) it prints (4,12)but      
     return (this.x, this.y);   //after returning (this.x, this.y) it   
                                //prints only Y coordinate as 12
}

var type_vector = new Vector(3, 3);

console.log(type_vector.plus(1, 9));
```

Output: `(3,3),(4,12),12`

Comment: I don't think you can return multiple values in parens like that. Instead you need to return an object `return { y: this.y, x: this.x };`

Comment: I don't think `return (x, y);` means what you think it means.

Comment: In javascript, U cant use `return (x , y);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in JavaScript if you want to return an array you can use the [] notation.

Diff. this with you version :

```
function Vector(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  console.log(x, y);
  return this;
}
Vector.prototype.plus = function(a, b) {
  this.x = this.x + a;
  this.y = this.y + b;
  console.log(this.x, this.y);
  return [this.x, this.y];
};
var type_vector = new Vector(3, 3);
console.log(type_vector.plus(1, 9));
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're from a python background, for there (x, y) is returned as a tuple. In JS if you return (x, y); it will be the value at the closing parenthesis (y, in this case). You must use an object or an array for your objective.

try this on console:

```
var a = (3, 4, 5, 6);
console.log(a);
```